# AppendText to constructed richTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, appendtext

I'm creating a new tab to my tabControl & a richtextbox inside of it.

But now I want to append new text into the richtextbox, but I don't know how to do it. (via another event, that is).

This is my current code for trying to AppendText to it:

```
RichTextBox achievementlog = new RichTextBox();
        achievementlog.AppendText("stackoverflow");
```

And here's my code for adding the tab and richtextbox, if that helps

```
//// Create the tab page:
            tabPage = new TabPage();
            tabPage.Name = "Achievements!";
            tabPage.Text = "Achievements!";
            tabPage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            RichTextBox achievementlog = new RichTextBox();

            //properties of richtextbox
            achievementlog.Text = "Achievements earned:\n-----------------------------\n\n";
            achievementlog.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            achievementlog.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))));
            achievementlog.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            achievementlog.ForeColor = Color.White;
            achievementlog.Width = 485;
            achievementlog.Height = 200;
            achievementlog.ReadOnly = true;

            //// Add the new tab page:
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
            tabPage.Controls.Add(achievementlog);
```

Comment: Winforms or WPF?  Both have an AppendText method, so what's the problem?  You might need an Invoke, if you're trying to do it from another thread.

Comment: I think you don't have `RichTextBox` instance with you since it is a local variable. Am I right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Right